# Slow requests running multiple workers

Tags: c#, .net, request, httpwebrequest

i implemented an application that perform web requests to a server. And works great, but i observed that the more workers i run, the slower request are. Workers are single threaded. This is my tests:

```
1 Process: 700ms  per request
2 Process: 900ms  per request
3 Process: 1000ms per request
4 Process: 1200ms per request
5 Process: 1400ms per request
6 Process: 2100ms per request
7 Process: 2400ms per request
8 Process: 2600ms per request
```

My CPU load (overall of 4 cores) never exceed 40%. So i'm guessing the server is limiting the number of simultaneous requests for my IP. Is that possible? Any ideas are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: There is many possibilities: 1) server not fast enough 2) server load balancing delaying request from same IP 4) TCP/IP issue on network or client side 5) request processing at client level 6) measurement issue. How many data are exchanged in each request ?

Comment: I think the issue may be in my internet connection. Each request is 320KB. Then with 8 processes i'm requesting 2.9MB. Shouldn't be a problem in production. Thank you!